# CSS Overlay one item over another

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar, that should be on top of everything else. I've tried using z-index, but it isn't working. This is my code:

```css
html {
    background-color: #2b2b3b;
    color: white;
}

#main {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

#top-ribbon {
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #202030;
    width: 10000px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div id="top-ribbon" style="z-index: 1; height: 100px">
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="z-index: -1">
            a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f<br>g<br>h<br>i<br>j<br>k<br>l<br>m<br>n<br>o<br>p<br>q<br>r<br>s<br>t<br>u<br>v<br>w<br>x<br>y<br>z<br>
            a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f<br>g<br>h<br>i<br>j<br>k<br>l<br>m<br>n<br>o<br>p<br>q<br>r<br>s<br>t<br>u<br>v<br>w<br>x<br>y<br>z<br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: it's already as described, it just has no background to be noticed, add something like `background: white;` to `#top-ribbon`

Comment: It's also worth noting that you haven't told the ribbon **where to be** with any position values....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ribbon has to have a background-color. It is transparent now.